# rails view replase "" on «»

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I'm trying to replace the quotes in the view. How it can be implemented? Database:

> "Info \"Company\""

view:

> Info "Company"

need to do

> Info «Company»

I tried to use gem 'gilenson'

```
<%= "#{@owner.name.gilensize}" %>
```

but on a view I get a string, like something with the .inspect method:

```
Info&#160;&#171;<span class="nobr">Company</span>&#187;
```

What better means to solve this problem? Thx.

Comment: mnemonic code in HTML is &laquo; &raquo;. And I have a lot of records on different pages. I would like a more general solution

Comment: Can you try given solution below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "Info \"Company\""
res = str.split('"')[0] + "&laquo;" + str.str.split('"')[1] + "&raquo;"

<%= res.html_safe %>
```

Or

I think you are missing `.html_safe` with  `gem 'gilenson'` try this: -

```
<%= @owner.name.gilensize.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I think of a more elegant solution, since there are so many lines, in different fields of the database it is necessary to edit

Comment: did you try this `<%= @owner.name.gilensize.html_safe %>` ?

Comment: thank you very much, gilensize.html_safe really is what I need.

Comment: @bigidigi89 Great to know that, feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you. for suture SO as well. :)

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to raise your rating, but I will definitely do it when I can. Thanks a lot for your help